# Sorting a list alphabetically from a CSV in Python by column

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I've written a piece of code that sends data to a .csv file, sorting by name, and then 3 scores from a quiz. I need to call that data from the .csv file created and sort the data alphabetically by name, numerically, and by average. However, when I try to sort the names alphabetically, nothing comes up. I'm quite new to Python so I can't see where my error is.

This is the part of my code that saves and (tries) to print the data.

```
if class_number == 2:
    f = open("Class 2" + ".csv", 'a')
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter =',')
    writer.writerow([name, count1, count2, count3])
    print ("Your scores were", count1, ",", count2, ", and", count3)

    print("Would you like to see previous results?")
    print("Press 1 to see previous results for your class. Press 2 to close the program")
    answer = int(input())
    if answer == 1:
        print("How would you like data to be sorted?")
        print("Press 1 for alphabetically")
        print("Press 2 for highest to lowest")
        print("Press 3 for average")
        score = input()
        if score == 1:
            sample = open("Class 2.csv", "r")
            csv1 = csv.reader(sample, delimiter=",")
            sort = sorted(csv1, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
            for eachline in sort:
                print("Class 2.csv", "r")
```

I'm really confused about what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: The part of code I need help with is

```
if score == 1:
            sample = open("Class 2.csv", "r")
            csv1 = csv.reader(sample, delimiter=",")
            sort = sorted(csv1, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
            for eachline in sort:
                print("Class 2.csv", "r")
```

This part will not display for some reason, but without the "If score" part it will display.

Comment: What it the exacpt problem here? which part of code?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this with a csv file with one column and it worked. I'm assuming you only want to display your result

```
import csv
import operator

sample = open("file.csv", "r")
csv_file = csv.reader(sample, delimiter=",")
sort = sorted(csv_file)
for eachline in sort:
    print eachline
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to keep the data read from csv file. And use the names as key. Then you can sort the keys and create a sorted list based on the sorted keys. Here is an example for sorting with names.

```
sample = open("example.csv", "r")
csv_file = csv.reader(sample, delimiter=",")

named = {}
for line in csv_file:
    # in case there are multiple entries with same name   
    # assuming names are in the first column
    named[line[0]] = named.get(line[0]) or []
    named[line[0]].append(line)

sorted_name_key = sorted(named)
name_sorted = []
for key in sorted_name_key:
    name_sorted.extend(named[key])
```

This way you can implement sorting for any column you want.